# How to generate xcframework with KMM; embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode only generates framework

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've created a KMM project, and also an Xcode project with a build phase that calls `./gradlew embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode`. It runs successfully, but generates a .framework, not an .xcframework; and we really need the latter for modern Xcode.

Am i missing something? I read that modern versions of kotlin can generate the xcframework directly, but i'm not sure how. Is there a gradle task for this?

Thanks so much :)

According to Kdoctor, I have:
Xcode 14.1
Android studio 2021.3
Kotlin Plugin: 213-1.7.20
Kotlin MM plugin: 0.5.1(213)-60

Answer (score 3):

You should declare your XCFrameworks, then it'll register three tasks for you.
`assembleXCFramework`, `assembleDebugXCFramework`, and `assembleReleaseXCFramework`.

Here is an example of build.gradle:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.apple.XCFramework

plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
   val xcf = XCFramework()
   val iosTargets = listOf(iosX64(), iosArm64(), iosSimulatorArm64())

   iosTargets.forEach {
      it.binaries.framework {
          baseName = "shared"
          xcf.add(this)
      }
   }
}
```

For more information, visit [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html#build-xcframeworks).

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your answer. The auto-generated `service/build.gradle.kts` file has most of what you describe above that I presume was generated by the kmm plugin. I added the `val xcf` and the `xcf.add(this)` to match your example, and re-ran `gradlew tasks` but could not see any `assembleXCFramework` tasks in the list, however. Thanks again.

Comment: I just created a new project and selected the XCFramework option and when I run `gradlew tasks`, I can see tasks related to generating XCFramework. Maybe you've selected another option for your output. It might be helpful if you paste your `build.gradle` file.